# Efficiently (time-wise) conversion of an array of double to a bitset, according to some function

Tags: c++, arrays, bitset

I need to interface between two pieces of code: one which outputs an "array" (I may accept output as either a "standard" `C++` array (of type double), or a `std::vector<double>`), and one which takes in a `std::bitset`.

Putting aside what goes on at either end...

**What is most efficient (time-wise) way to convert the output array to a `std::bitset`, according to some function?**

By this I mean, for each element in the output bitset, I want to assign a value (`0` or `1`) according to some function (e.g., elements greater than `N` are assigned a value of `1`, elements less than `N` are assigned a value of `0`... or all even elements are assigned a value of `1`, etc).

The obvious (and, perhaps, simplest) method is, of course, to use a loop. E.g., something like (in the case of value comparison):

```
L = outputVector.size();
std::bitset<L> inputBitset;
for(int i = 0; i < L; ++i){
   if(outputVector[i] > N){
      inputBitset[i] == 1;
   }
}
```

I've also considered doing something with `std::replace_if()` (e.g., replacing all values greater than `N` with a `1`, then iterating over the "array" afterwards and setting bits accordingly), which may offer a speed improvement (although it seems *incredibly* clunky).

Where *speed* is the only thing I'm concerned about, is there a better way?

Comment: By "'standard' `C++` array (of type double)", do you mean a C++ standard array as in `std::array<double, 32>` or a **C**-style array, as in `double X[32]`?

Comment: Note that `L` is not known at compile time (if it's a `std::vector`, not clear from your question), so it can't be used to construct the `bitset`. But in any case, it's hard to see getting much faster than this, except maybe by avoiding the branch and just unconditionally setting `inputBitset[i] = outputVector[i] > N`. But as with most performance questions, you'll have benchmark it and see.

Comment: @JaMiT I mean the former `std::array<double,32>`. I'll clarify that above.

Comment: Why do you think that iterating over your source array twice (once with `std::replace_if` and once to set bits) might be faster than iterating over it just once?

Comment: @JaMiT As you point out, I very much doubt it is, I simply mentioned the option as I've been surprised before at how such unintuitive changes have lead to measurable performance improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely pattern that your compiler will be able to vectorize is simply setting the result to comparison result directly

```
for (int i = 0; i < L; ++i)
    inputBitset[i] = outputVector[i] > N;
```

Such loops will generally be vectorized if your processor supports it.  More complex loops may also be vectorized, so would end up with the same result, but there's no reason to make the code more complex than it needs to be.